# How to write(enable) Java code in HTML while using GWT 2.5?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.5

I've started taking advantage of GWT 2.5.  The coolest [feature](https://plus.google.com/117487419861992917007/posts/Cg9vEE9csXS) of GWT 2.5 was the ability to write Java code directly in our HTML pages like so:

```
<script type="text/java">
   String helloWorld = "Hello world";
   Window.alert(helloWorld);
</script>
```

The trick is to use a `ServletFilter` on the server side. This `ServletFilter` uses the GWT compiler to compile this java code into Javascript and inject it into the HTML returned to the client.

I am unable to figure out how to filter this in `web.xml` or how to pass information to the compiler.  How can I do this?

Comment: can you provide me the link of the google docs for this, i want to look into this feature...

Comment: Unable to find the Google doc for that.Lets hope someone will give a solution or link regarding that .I started it by reading https://plus.google.com/117487419861992917007/posts/Cg9vEE9csXS

Comment: I actually don't think this is an out of the box feature, but only to show what `SuperDevMode` and `Elemental` can do together, by simply code a `ServletFilter` that catches every `<script type="text/java">` in an `html` page, synthesizes an on-the-fly module entry point, compiles in one second and replaces the script content with the output of the compilation. Unfortunately I don't think such a filter is available, you should ask Ray directly, through the G+ community, or the GWT-contributors group.

Comment: @Andrea Boscolo .thanks for the information.I'l do that and raise a ticket on G groups too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Google I/O 2012 - The History and Future of Google Web Toolkit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOf27ez_Hvg) you are referring too. And here are the [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1pC9WK80-fzIs2iMQOO3Jsvfmqv2erI9xucuF3lHOE7Q/) posted by Ray Cromwell.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for the valuable links.But there I didn't get how to use the above feature there.Only explanation about the feature is there.